Gauss-Manin connection, base change and projection formula
Let $X$, $Y$ be complex analytic manifolds, and $f : X \to Y$ a proper, smooth morphism (i.e. smooth fibers). In every course talking about the Gauss-Manin connection, you find the following formula :
$$R^k f_* \mathbb C_X \otimes_{\mathbb C} \mathcal O_Y \simeq R^kf_*\Omega_{X/Y}^\bullet$$
and I really can't figure out where it comes from. I know that $\Omega^\bullet_{X/Y}$ is quasi-isomorphic to $f^{-1}\mathcal O_Y$, and most courses mention using base change theorems (which I know about, but involve $f_*$ and $f^*$ rather than $f^{-1}$) and the projection formula - which to be fair I don't really know about, but looking it up gives a thousand different definitions, none of which seem to work here - and I really couldn't find any details on the proof whatsoever.
I tried proving it using that $\mathbb C_X$ is quasi-isomorphic to the De Rham Complex, and playing around with exact sequences, but it didn't work. I also tried to play around with base change, like using $R^k f_* \mathcal E = q^* R^k p_* \mathcal E$ where $p,q$ are the moprhisms $X \to \{*\}$ and $Y \to \{*\}$, applied to $\mathcal E = f^{-1} \mathcal O_Y$, but it doesn't exactly give me what I want.
